# Laravel Checking If a Record Exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, conditional-statements

I am new to Laravel. How do I find if a record exists?

```php
$user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'));
```

What can I do here to see if `$user` has a record?

Comment: Well to start you need to execute a findOrFail() or similar on the $user query

Comment: that doesn't really help

Comment: Then what does it do? Why doesn't it help? `$user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'));` simply creates a query in `$user`, you need to execute that query. `findOrFail()` is one way of executing that query. `get()` would be another way, `firstOrFail()` another

Comment: If a suggestion "doesn't really help" try saying ___why___ it doesn't really help, because that way it means we know how to improve/change that suggestion

Comment: consider this https://i.imgur.com/ulqyOiw.png no need to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 845, accepted):

It depends if you want to work with the user afterwards or only check if one exists.

If you want to use the user object if it exists:

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->first();
if ($user === null) {
   // user doesn't exist
}
```

And if you only want to check

```
if (User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->count() > 0) {
   // user found
}
```

Or even nicer

```
if (User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->exists()) {
   // user found
}
```

Comment: if you call `exists()` against a non existent  record then it gives error: `Call to a member function exists() on null`

Comment: @Volatil3 You are doing something wrong. You can't call exists after you've already ran the query

Comment: @lukasgeiter guess you are right. I had already called `first()`

Comment: I used to use -> $email_exists = DB::table('users')->select('email')->where('email', $request->email)->count(); but your method is better :)

Comment: alternatively, `if (!User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->exists())...` could work

Comment: I think this is the better way to find if User is exists. User::where('email', '=', 'value')->count() > 0;

Comment: @JanakaPushpakumara That alone has sometimes caused me error. I also add  `&& isset()`

Comment: exists() might be a good option too but I feel like it is not the most optimised way, is it?

Comment: @Volatil3 i just tested ->exists() with laravel 5.5, it says false if it doesn't exist.

Comment: FYI, you can leave out the '=' value:

`User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->exists();`

Comment: Why making SQL to continue counting rows with `count` after it has already found one? `Exists` is more appropriate here - it stops right after finding one match. Even if performance difference might be negligible, still it expresses the intention better.

Comment: What if you want to check for multiple row exist?

Comment: @Pezhvak Same here with laravel 7.x

Comment: in laravel 8.x ;exists() returns false if no row found.so it is safe to use.

Comment: Not working with milliseconds case. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 85):

```
if (User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->exists()) {
    // exists
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The most efficient and dedicated way to do it is through the `exists()` method.

Answer (score 47):

In laravel eloquent, has default `exists()` method, refer followed example.

```
if (User::where('id', $user_id )->exists()) {
    // your code...
}
```

Answer (score 32):

One of the best solution is to use the `firstOrNew` or `firstOrCreate` method. The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#other-creation-methods) has more details on both.

Comment: while not fitting the question, still, very useful functions. the difference between the two is that firstOrNew **instantiates** an instance of the model called while firstOrCreate saves the queried model instantly so you need to update changes on the firstOrCreate'd model.

Comment: Yep, or another way of thinking of it is, use *firstOrCreate* if you can pass all the attributes in one go (use the second parameter), but *firstOrNew* if you're going to need further logic before saving.

Answer (score 20):

```
if($user->isEmpty()){
    // has no records
}
```

Eloquent uses collections. 
See the following link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections

Comment: Yeah but its not returning a collection. It's returning a single model object as you would assume each user has a unique `email` so `->isEmpty()` will throw an error.

Comment: And what if I get the following error: `Call to a member function isEmpty() on null`

Answer (score 13):

Laravel 5.6.26v

to find the existing record through primary key ( email or id )

```
    $user = DB::table('users')->where('email',$email)->first();
```

then

```
      if(!$user){
             //user is not found 
      }
      if($user){
             // user found 
      }
```

include " use DB " and table name user become plural using the above query like user to users

Answer (score 12):

It is a bit late but it might help someone who is trying to use `User::find()->exists()` for record existence as Laravel shows different behavior for `find()` and `where()` methods. Considering email as your primary key let's examine the situation.

```
$result = User::find($email)->exists();
```

If a user record with that email exists then it will return `true`. However the confusing thing is that if no user with that email exists then it will throw an error. i.e

```
Call to a member function exists() on null.
```

But the case is different for `where()` thing.

```
$result = User::where("email", $email)->exists();
```

The above clause will give `true` if record exists and `false` if record doesn't exists. So always try to use `where()` for record existence and not `find()` to avoid `NULL` error.

Answer (score 9):

```
if (User::where('email', 'user@email.com')->first()) {
    // It exists
} else {
    // It does not exist
}
```

Use `first()`, not `count()` if you only need to check for existence.

`first()` is **faster** because it checks for a single match whereas `count()` counts all matches.

Answer (score 9):

This will check if requested email exist in the user table:

```
if (User::where('email', $request->email)->exists()) {
   //email exists in user table
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**In your Controller**

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|unique:user|email',
    ]);
```

**In your View - Display Already Exist Message**

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this, using empty() function:

```
$user = User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->get()->first();
//for example:
if (!empty($user))
    User::destroy($user->id);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$user = User::where('email', request('email'))->first();
return (count($user) > 0 ? 'Email Exist' : 'Email Not Exist');
```

Answer (score 2):

Checking for `null` within `if` statement prevents Laravel from returning 404 immediately after the query is over.

```
if ( User::find( $userId ) === null ) {

    return "user does not exist";
}
else {
    $user = User::find( $userId );

    return $user;
}
```

It seems like it runs double query if the user is found, but I can't seem to find any other reliable solution.

Comment: You could replace `find` with `where`. `User::where(id, 1)->first()`

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($u = User::where('email', '=', $value)->first())
{
   // do something with $u
   return 'exists';
} else {
  return 'nope';
}
```

would work with try/catch

->get() would still return an empty array

Answer (score 2):

```
$email = User::find($request->email);
If($email->count()>0)
<h1>Email exist, please make new email address</h1>
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple, comfortable and understandable with **Validator**

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:customers',
            'phone' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:customers',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response(['errors' => $validator->errors()->all()], 422);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you have seen plenty of solution, but magical checking syntax can be like,

```
$model = App\Flight::findOrFail(1);

$model = App\Flight::where('legs', '>', 100)->firstOrFail();
```

it will automatically raise an exception with response 404, when not found any related models Sometimes you may wish to throw an exception if a model is not found. This is particularly useful in routes or controllers. The fingernail and firstOrFail methods will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Answer (score 1):

This will check if particular email address exist in the table:

```
if (isset(User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->value('email')))
{
    // Input::get('email') exist in the table 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest working options:

```
// if you need to do something with the user 
if ($user = User::whereEmail(Input::get('email'))->first()) {

    // ...

}

// otherwise
$userExists = User::whereEmail(Input::get('email'))->exists();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->first();
if ($user === null) {
   // user doesn't exist
}
```

can be written as

```
if (User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->first() === null) {
   // user doesn't exist
}
```

This will return true or false without assigning a temporary variable if that is all you are using $user for in the original statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think below way is the simplest way to achieving same :

```
    $user = User::where('email', '=', $request->input('email'))->first();
    if ($user) {
       // user exist!
    }else{
       // user does not exist
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel validation if you want to insert a unique record:

```
$validated = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:usersTable,emailAddress|max:255',
]);
```

But also you can use these ways:

1:

```
if (User::where('email',  $request->email)->exists())
{
  // object exists
} else {
  // object not found
}
```

2:

```
$user = User::where('email',  $request->email)->first();

if ($user)
{
  // object exists
} else {
  // object not found
}
```

3:

```
$user = User::where('email',  $request->email)->first();

if ($user->isNotEmpty())
{
  // object exists
} else {
  // object not found
}
```

4:

```
$user = User::where('email',  $request->email)->firstOrCreate([
      'email' => 'email'
],$request->all());
```

Comment: Please consider that `count` method counts records and it is not good performance-wise in this scenario.

Comment: @AliN11
I did not use `count` method

Answer (score 0):

Created below method (for myself) to check if the given record id exists on Db table or not.

```
private function isModelRecordExist($model, $recordId)
{
    if (!$recordId) return false;

    $count = $model->where(['id' => $recordId])->count();

    return $count ? true : false;
}

// To Test
$recordId = 5;
$status = $this->isModelRecordExist( (new MyTestModel()), $recordId);
```

Home It helps!

Comment: Note that by using `count`, you are counting a certain record throughout the table. While the `exists` method returns `true` if the table contains at least one desired record.

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest Way to do

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
{


    $coupon = Coupon::where('name','=',$request->name)->first(); 

    if($coupon->id != $id){
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'discount' => 'required',   
            'name' => 'required|unique:coupons|max:255',      
        ]);
    }


    $requestData = $request->all();
    $coupon = Coupon::findOrFail($id);
    $coupon->update($requestData);
    return redirect('admin/coupons')->with('flash_message', 'Coupon updated!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 6 or on the top:** Write the table name, then give where clause condition for instance **where('id', $request->id)**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $target = DB:: table('categories')
                ->where('title', $request->name)
                ->get()->first();
        if ($target === null) { // do what ever you need to do
            $cat = new Category();
            $cat->title = $request->input('name');
            $cat->parent_id = $request->input('parent_id');
            $cat->user_id=auth()->user()->id;
            $cat->save();
            return redirect(route('cats.app'))->with('success', 'App created successfully.');

        }else{ // match found 
            return redirect(route('cats.app'))->with('error', 'App already exists.');
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a record in the database if a record with the same email not exists then you can do as follows:

```
$user = User::updateOrCreate(
    ['email' => Input::get('email')],
    ['first_name' => 'Test', 'last_name' => 'Test']
);
```

The `updateOrCreate` method's first argument lists the column(s) that uniquely identify records within the associated table while the second argument consists of the values to insert or update.

You can check out the docs here: [Laravel upserts doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts)

Answer (score 0):

```
$userCnt     = User::where("id",1)->count();
if( $userCnt ==0 ){
     //////////record not exists 
}else{
      //////////record exists 
}
```

Note :: Where  condition according your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply use this one to get true or false

   $user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->exists();
2. if you want $user with result you can use this one,

   $user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->get();

and check result like this,

```
if(count($user)>0){}
```

3. Other wise you can use like this one,

   $user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'));

   if($user->exists()){
   $user = $user->get();
   }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for a boolean result as true or false

```
$columns = [
    'email' => "email@example.com",
];
$exists = User::exists($columns);

if($exists)
     ...some code
```

Answer (score -1):

The efficient way to check if the record exists you must use is_null method to check against the query.

The code below might be helpful:

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'));
if(is_null($user)){
 //user does not exist...
}else{
 //user exists...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Controller :

```
            public function validation(Request $request)
            {
            $email= $request->input('email');

            if (DB::table('customer')->where('email','=',$email)->exists())
            {
                echo 'EXIST';
            } else {
                echo 'DOESNT EXIST';
            }}
```

HTML form :

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
```

Route :

```
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class,'validation']);
```

Answer (score -4):

It's simple to get to know if there are any records or not

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->get();
if(count($user) > 0)
{
echo "There is data";
}
else
echo "No data";
```

Comment: Fetching all records, then counting?!

Answer (score -15):

**this is simple code to check email is exist or not in database**

```
    $data = $request->all();
    $user = DB::table('User')->pluck('email')->toArray();
    if(in_array($user,$data['email']))
    {
    echo 'existed email';
    }
```

Comment: If you have a table User with ...say over1,000,000,000 records, you'll be checking for a veeeeeeery long time