# Check if string is already in database or not in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, string, laravel

Here is my code

```
$string = str_random(20);
$get_token = DB::table('users')->select('token')-> get();
```

now I want to compare `$string` with `$get_token` . if it is not in database then it should add to database with the value `$string` has.

I have written this code.

```
if(strcmp($string , $get_token) !=0){
//add to DB
}
```

How can i compare my string to each of the string which is already in database.

Thank You

Comment: Do you use `Models`?

Comment: Yes... I do use User Model.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095090/laravel-checking-if-record-exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Models, you can run this code:

```
$token = str_random(20); //makes an random string with 20 characters
//select all tokens in the User model where token = $token and count it
$get_token = User::where('token', $token)->count(); //laravel returns an integer

if($get_token == 0) {
    //the token doesn't exist
    //Run the create token code
} else {
    //Token exist
}
```

Hope this works!

---

**What are Models?**

> The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple
>   ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database. Each
>   database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact
>   with that table. Models allow you to query for data in your tables, as
>   well as insert new records into the table.

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

You can make a check in database if `$string` not exit then you can insert into database.

Take a look following code :

```
 $string = str_random(20);
 $get_token = DB::table('users')->where('token', '=', $string)->first();// get first record for that database.

 if(empty($get_token->token))
 {

 //if token not exit in database insert it into database.
  DB::table('users')->insert(
    array('token' =>$string )
  );

 }
```

Comment: `$email_id = Input::get('email_id');                                               $api_token = str_random(50);

        if (User::where('api_token', '=', $api_token)->exists()) {
            $get_api_token = User::select('api_token')
                             -> where('email_id', '=', $email_id)
                             -> get();
        }

        else{
            DB::table('users')-> insertGetId(array( // insert new user in database
                'email_id' => $email_id,
                'api_token' => $api_token
            ));

        }`

Comment: this is i want to do... if i get token which is exists in DB then return that token for given email id and if not then insert the token with given email_id

Comment: what the error you are getting, its working for you or not ?

Comment: `'<' unexpected ` in JSON