# How to check if values from the table 1 are used in table 2?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables `employees` and `departments`.

Departments:

```
create table dept (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
dept_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Employees:

```
create table department_master (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
dept_id INT NOT NULL, 
emp_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I want to prevent departments being deleted from the UI if they are assigned to one of the employees in employee table. Left join is giving me duplicate values.

How do I see if the departments are being used in the employees table.

Comment: You are asking for select .... where ??

Comment: @scaisEdge I tried join but I did not get the desired result. So I want to know if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel checking if record exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095090/laravel-checking-if-record-exists)

Comment: if you need  only  a simple check you can use  a select where  .. if this is clear  .. ok otherwise let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent a department from being deleted, you can simply add a foreign constraint to the table `department_master` for dept_id column.

```
create table department_master (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dept_id INT NOT NULL, 
    emp_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    constraint con_dm foreign key dept_id references dept( id )
);
```

It's default behavior is `ON DELETE RESTRICT` which means that if there is atleast one row present in the department_master for a given dept_id, it can't be deleted from dept table.

If you want to fetch, the department that don't have any employee record, you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from dept d
where not exists (
        select 1
        from department_master m
        where d.id = m.dept_id
        );
```

Comment: @Krish please note the storage engine should be InnoDB for this to work

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want a count of the number of employees grouped by the department, like so:

```
SELECT count(*) as employees, d.dept_name  FROM dept AS d LEFT JOIN department_master AS e ON e.dept_id = d.id group by e.dept_id
```