# check if record exist in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I have a dynamic input form, I want to check if the record exists, if no then it can not insert data

my controller

```
$user = Master::where('id_a','=',$request->get('id_a'))->where('id_b','=',$request->get('id_b'))->get();

   if($user->isEmpty()){
      // insert
   }else{
     //message "cannot input"
   }
```

if insert one data, success.. but if insert array in my controller not check..
why in input array data always insert???

Comment: can you show the insert code

Comment: $input = $request->all();
            for ($i=0; $i < count($request->get('id_b')); ++$i) 
            {
                 $var = new Master;        
                 $var->value= $input['value'][$i];
                 $var->save();  
             }

Comment: if insert one data, always check to database, but if insert array data not check.

Comment: is $request->get('id_b') contain an array. In that case you have to use `whereIn` not `where`

Comment: @HoàngĐăng i got error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" if use whereIn

Comment: i just want to check if row exist in `DB` ..

Comment: wait i will make a simple example for you

Comment: ok thank @HoàngĐăng

Comment: i posted if you need more explain, tell me, but my solution still not perfect way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel checking if record exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095090/laravel-checking-if-record-exists)

Comment: @andrewnagyeb maybe but he want to do as bulk action

Answer (score 1):

This is pseudo for only check `id_b`

```
   $data = [1,2,3,4];
   $data_a = [1,2,3,4];

    $masters = Master::whereIn('id_b', $data)->whereIn('id_a', $data_a)->get();

    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $isExisted = false;

        foreach ($masters as $master) {
            if ($master->id_b == $value[$key] && $master->id_a == $data_a[$key])
            {
                $isExisted = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( ! $isExisted) {
            $master = new Banner();
            $master->value = your_data;
            $master->save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but not work :(

Comment: check your `$request->get('id_a')` and `id_b` is an array, if not parse them to array

Comment: if you have code in github I can debug for u

Comment: i not use github..
but thanks..
i check in `dd()` `$request->get('id_b')` null.. why?

Comment: re-check in browser. Did you sent it

Comment: ops i check in browser, $request return array.. whats wrong?

Comment: try dd($request->all())

Comment: $request return array..

Comment: if i use `whereIn` error invalid argument supplied foreach()

Comment: because $request->get('id_b') is not an array, you have to find where is your 'id_b' array gone

Answer (score 0):

You could use exists()

```
if(Master::where('id_a','=',$request->get('id_a'))->where('id_b','=',$request->get('id_b'))->exists()) {
do something
}
```

Also I would suggest you reduce the amount of in-line stuff you're doing, instead something like this:

```
$id_a = $request->get('id_a');
$id_b = $request->get('id_b');

if(Master::where('id_a','=', $id_a)->where('id_b','=',$id_b)->exists()) {
do something
}
```

Comment: $id_a, $id_b is an array for his case

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to insert a `Master` if a given `id_a` and `id_b`  doesn't already exists for one *Master*

If so, you could actually use [firstOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) :

```
Master::firstOrCreate(
  ['id_a' => $request->get('id_a'), 'id_b' => $request->get('id_b')], 
  ['yourcolumntocreate' => columnvalue, ...]
)
```

Comment: if i use firstOrCreate old data has been replace..

Comment: You could `firstOrNew` then, but I think it's not your problem...