# How to check if pricing_plan_id exist for a user or not?

Tags: php, laravel

i am making a free bonus plan in my laravel web . i want if a user has already claimed bonus plan then he should not be able to claim it again . i want  that if pricing_plan_id is already in plan_logs with that user id it should return error.

i am able to check if record exist for user or not with below code but i want to only find if that it exist or not.

```
 $plan = PlanLog::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('pricing_plan_id', $plan->cat_id)->get();

    if (empty($plan)) {
       return redirect()->back()->with('type','danger')->with('message','please add funds atleast once');
    }
```

Comment: Is the topic on the link outdated for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095090/laravel-checking-if-a-record-exists/35561241

Comment: yes its checking record only

Comment: So can you edit your question? I think it is not so clear.