# html tripled in size by returning empty tags after a mysql query | how to solve - laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, string, laravel

How to list data from an unauthenticated user (public page) looking for their name? I would also like to know if it is possible to convert the username by id internally.

I have two tables, 1st companies and 2nd personalities,in my code, I take the string "name" from the URL and do a search on the 1st table (companies), if positive, I send this name to the view, where I need to list data this user who are present in the personalities table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ahvx.png)

I don't know what I did wrong, but the code triples the html and doesn't return the way I want.

I need to return this way:

```xml
<div class="bg-danger"><br><br></div>
<div class="bg-primary"><br><br></div>
<div class="bg-success"><br><br></div>
<div class="bg-info"><br><br></div>
```

follow the code

**router**

```php
Route::get('company/{name}', 'CompanyController@searchByName');
```

**controller**

```php
public function searchByName($name)
{
    $company = Company::where('name', $name)->first();
    return view('company.base.index', compact('company', 'name'));
}
```

**view**

```xml
<!--- Lochlite: version 3.0.0 country Brazil, lang PT-BR, official site Gameloch Brasil © 2015 - 2019 Gameloch All Right Reserved. --->
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:og="https://ogp.me/ns#" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Corporation" class="no-js" lang="pt pt-BR_ALL" user-region="">
<head data-info="" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="origin" name="referrer">
    <meta name="geo.country" content="BR">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="4rtTcBa4csPFlBtHECAmTw6MAh8D5y4ni0H5h49S">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
</body>
    @foreach($company as $company)
        <div class="{{ DB::table('personalities')->select('div_class_1')->where('name', '=', $name)->get() }}"><br><br></div>
        <div class="{{ DB::table('personalities')->select('div_class_2')->where('name', '=', '$name')->get() }}"><br><br></div>
        <div class="{{ DB::table('personalities')->select('div_class_3')->where('name', '=', '$name')->get() }}"><br><br></div>
        <div class="{{ DB::table('personalities')->select('div_class_4')->where('name', '=', '$name')->get() }}"><br><br></div>
    @endforeach      
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**return**

```xml
<div class="[{&quot;div_class_1&quot;:&quot;bg-danger&quot;}]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[{&quot;div_class_1&quot;:&quot;bg-danger&quot;}]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[{&quot;div_class_1&quot;:&quot;bg-danger&quot;}]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[{&quot;div_class_1&quot;:&quot;bg-danger&quot;}]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[]"><br><br></div>
<div class="[]"><br><br></div>
```

Comment: `foreach ($company as $company)` ...  and what are you trying to iterate through on that `$company` model?

Comment: well, the same, see the picture I put

Comment: look at the controller, it takes the url name and checks if it exists in the table, $ company returns the name entered after site.com/company/

Comment: you have a single model instance, what do you think iterating over that will do?

Comment: in vista I used where ('name', '=', $ name) because I already used company there, so nothing will return if you use it again,  $ name has the same function

Comment: I created a template yes, but I have not put anything, because it was working like this, I need to return the database data to change the page layout

Comment: why do you have a loop there at all? You only have 1 Company, not many

Comment: To be honest, @foreach ($ company as $ company) shouldn't be there, but if I don't put it in, I can't get $name from the controller, I've already tried

Comment: correct the loop should not be there as it obviously isn't what you want to happen but you are incorrect about needing it

Comment: I just need to get the data from the columns in the personality table, this data must be related to this user, the data from the whole table or from other users cannot be shown.

Comment: i dont see any reference to a user in the code

Comment: I tried to use something like this: {{auth () -> user () -> name}}, but as you know, it should not work because there is no one authenticated

Comment: the name is the reference 'Route :: get (' company / {name} 'is a user customized page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing what you need for the view into the view, including the query on `personalities`:

```
public function searchByName($name)
{
    $company = Company::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();
    $personality = DB::table('personalities')->where('name', $name)->first();

    return view('company.base.index', compact('company', 'name', 'personality'));
}
```

View:

```
<div class="{{ $personality->div_class_1 }}"><br><br></div>
<div class="{{ $personality->div_class_2 }}"><br><br></div>
<div class="{{ $personality->div_class_3 }}"><br><br></div>
<div class="{{ $personality->div_class_4 }}"><br><br></div>
```

No loop needed as there is nothing to iterate over.

Comment: Symfony \ Componente \ Depuração \ Exceção \ FatalThrowableError
Classe 'App \ Http \ Controllers \ DB' not found

Comment: namespacing, `use DB;` above the controller class declaration

Comment: You are a genius, thank you so much for your help. I would like to vote for your answer to increase your reputation, but it is not possible at this time.

Comment: it is no problem ... what did you want to do with the `id` instead of the `name` ?

Comment: I was here weighing in the case of two companies with the same name, there would be conflict

Comment: you could switch to using the `id` or hashid in the url instead of the name if you would like

Comment: would it be possible to prevent the registration of two with this name in the form?

Comment: yes, you could use validation to make that field 'unique'   https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Last question, how could I put an exception in the controller if the name does not exist?

Comment: updated the answer, you can change `first()` to `firstOrFail()` which will throw a `ModelNotFoundException` if it can't find a record