# The error response that appears is the status code 200

Tags: php, laravel, rest, postman

I am in learning rest API laravel, in this case
**I want to limit the user to only be able to create 1 team**, but after just testing with Postman, when the user has created more than 1 team, the default display is Laravel's status code 200
what should appear is the error response that I have set

[image: error view]

Here is my code:

##### Controller

```
public function createTeam(CreateTeamRequest $request)
{

    try {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $team = Team::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
        $access_token = $user->remember_token;
        if ($team->user_id->exists()) {
            return $this->messageError('Kamu hanya dapat membuat 1 team!', 422);
        } else {
            $team = Team::create(array_merge(
                $request->all(),
                [
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                ]
            ));
            return $this->messageSuccess(['data' => $team, 'header' => ['access_token' => $access_token]], "Berhasil membuat tim", 200);
        }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $this->messageError('Terjadi Kesalahan' . $e->getMessage(), 422);
    }

}
```

##### Model

```php
class Team extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

}
```

##### Migration

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });

    Schema::create('team_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('team_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

        $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('teams')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['team_id', 'user_id']);
    });

}
```

I want when a user has created more than one team, an error message will appear.

Comment: Just dump your `$team` variable in your code, using Xdebug for example and debug your code, I don't understand `$team->user_id->exists()`, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095090/laravel-checking-if-a-record-exists

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck? Are you sure this problem is in any way related to Postman?

Comment: @VincentDecaux ,what $team->user_id->exists() means I want to check if the team was created again by the same user_id ? because I want to limit the user to only be able to create 1 team

Comment: 1. please change the `accept` header to `application/json`

2. `dd()` each block to see if you actually are in the intended block

3. `HttpResponseException` is a better approach to handle error responses while you're developing a RESTful API

Comment: if I were you, I'd create a custom validation rule and used it in `CreateTeamRequest ` class

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function createTeam(CreateTeamRequest $request)
{
    try {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $access_token = $user->remember_token;

        if ($user->team()->exists()) {
            return $this->messageError('Kamu hanya dapat membuat 1 team!', 422);
        } else {
            $team = Team::query()->create(array_merge(
                $request->validated(),
                [
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                ]
            ));
            return $this->messageSuccess(['data' => $team, 'header' => ['access_token' => $access_token]], "Berhasil membuat tim", 200);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $this->messageError('Terjadi Kesalahan' . $e->getMessage(), 500);
    }
}
```

Here I use `team()` relationship defined in `App\Models\User::class` to check if this user already has a team.

Comment: thank you for the answer, the team() function is not recognized even though I have called the class use App\Models\User , but I tried with $user->team but the result is that when a user creates a team of more than 1 a status code 200 will appear

Comment: @zal you need to define the team relation in your `App\Models\User::class`, similar to how you have done for `members()`

Comment: @zal if the `team()` relation is not defined, `$user->team` will always be `null` and your check will fail.